# How to interprete an iso8601 string with daylight saving info?

Tags: jq

The following two iso8601 strings both mean the beginning of the respective day. But since EST has been changed to EDT between the two dates, the second time string is interpreted as 1am instead of 0am. Is there a way to let jq be aware of the daylight saving when processing an iso8601 string?

```
$ jq fromdateiso8601 <<< '"2022-03-11T05:00:00Z"'
1646974800
$ jq fromdateiso8601 <<< '"2022-03-14T04:00:00Z"'
1647234000
$ TZ=America/New_York date --date=@1646974800
Fri Mar 11 00:00:00 EST 2022
$ TZ=America/New_York date --date=@1647234000
Mon Mar 14 01:00:00 EDT 2022
$ jq --version
jq-1.6
```

I run jq on macOSX.

EDIT:

```
$ jq -r todateiso8601 <<<'1647230400'
2022-03-14T04:00:00Z
$ date -d '2022-03-14T04:00:00Z' '+%s'
1647230400
$ date -d @1647230400 --iso=seconds --utc
2022-03-14T04:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Tip: `.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|...` and `.|...` can be written as `...`

Comment: A good test could be to try the reverse with the correct unix ts: `jq todateiso8601 <<<'1647230400'`. Returns `"2022-03-14T04:00:00Z"` on Linux. Also, what does MacOs returns on: `date -d '2022-03-14T04:00:00Z' '+%s'` and `date -d @1647230400 --iso=seconds --utc`

Comment: I've updated the post. It seems that date works correctly on macOSX. So the bug is solely in jq instead of on the macOSX library  that jq depends on?

Answer (score 0):

`2022-03-14T04:00:00Z` is `1647230400`, not `1647234000`.

I get the correct result with jq 1.6 on Ubuntu:

```
$ jq fromdateiso8601 <<<'"2022-03-14T04:00:00Z"'
1647230400
```

I get the same incorrect result with jq 1.6 on Cygwin:

```
$ jq fromdateiso8601 <<<'"2022-03-14T04:00:00Z"'
1647234000
```

(`fromdateiso8601` is simply not supported on Windows.)

There's a bug somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: It is wrong on macOSX in my case. What is it wrong in macOSX and Cygwin that causes this error? Is it a bug in jq or there is a bug in the library that jq depends on?

Comment: I don't know. It could be either